# Pycharm Import Error

Tags: python, django, pycharm, importerror

guys. I'm trying to develop a program to create excel file with using xlwt.
I have used

```
pip install xlwt
```

to install it. In Terminal, it can be imported with no error. And the Django project could be run correctly.

But in pycharm, it shows import error when running the Django project. The error code shows below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/motion/Documents/GitHub/motion-op/motion/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from product.views import home
  File "/Users/motion/Documents/GitHub/motion-op/product/views.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .ProductService import ProductService
  File "/Users/motion/Documents/GitHub/motion-op/product/ProductService.py", line 13, in <module>
    from method import ProductServicePO,send_email, SaveImg, create_excel_file
  File "/Users/motion/Documents/GitHub/motion-op/product/method/create_excel_file.py", line 2, in <module>
    import xlwt
ImportError: No module named xlwt
```

I have already set project interpreter. [The project interpreter image shows here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5He9l.jpg)

Does anyone know how to solve it, thanks guys.

Comment: What interpreter are you using in the run config?

Comment: Can you try your pip install command after opening the terminal inside of pyCharm?  Assuming your project is already open and your interpreter is set.  I think you pip installed into the vanillia Python environment.

Comment: I'm using python2.7

Comment: It says 'Requirement already satisfied: xlwt in /Users/motion/aws_env_lzy/lib/python2.7/site-packages
'. @Kyle

Comment: In that same terminal window are you running the django server to trigger the original error?

Comment: try to install and run using `pycharm terminal` ( make sure that, pycharm terminal is belongs to your `virtual env` something like this -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO55h.png )

Comment: In the terminal inside of pycharm, it runs correctly when running django server.

Comment: If you want to run it outside of the pycharm environment, you need to explicitly source the python virtual environment that contains your django / xlwt packages.

Comment: Got it, Kyle. But in pycharm, I can not run it with clicking start button. It says no module named xlwt.T-T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit the `pip list` command on pycharm's terminal and see whether `xlwt` available there or not. If not install it again.You are using python 2.7 so, see the version of xlwt you are using is compatible with this python or not.

Edited:

If you want to run your project with start button then go to `edit configuration by clicking on drop-down button beside the start and set the python interpreter there.

Apart from that, you need to see `from .ProductService import ProductService` (try writing full path instead of just typing .productService) and `from method import ProductServicePO,send_email, SaveImg, create_excel_file` import line in `views.py` and `ProductService.py` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Set project intepretator for current project. You probably set for common project

Answer (score 0):

Just faced same problem and fixed it.

Configure your current interpreter in pycharm. (ctrl+alt+s)

Click '+' icon on the right side and install xlwt.

Install successfully with a pop-ups from pycharm and import problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install through the Pycharm's GUI directly. Look in the following:

`File|Settings|Project:|Python Interpreter| add`

then search for `xlwt` and install.

Answer (score 0):

Went to Python Packages at the bottom of PyCharm, found xlwt and installed from there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).